# Assistive Technology for Hands Free Use

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, software-recommendation, application-development

I'm looking for packages compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS that facilitate using the computer without hands.
Examples include:

- eye gaze tracking mouse software
- dictation software capable of coding

Strong preference to users who have experience with the packages they are recommending. I tried to install https://eviacam.crea-si.com/index.php but it is broken for Ubuntu 20.04 :/

Comment: Have you tried official package from Ubuntu repositories at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/eviacam ?  It is installable as simple as `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install eviacam` ...

Comment: got this error:
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cesar-crea-si/eviacam/ubuntu focal Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cesar-crea-si/eviacam/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

The [mentioned PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecesar-crea-si/+archive/ubuntu/eviacam) does not provide packages for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it was last updated for 16.04 LTS. You have to remove it first by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:cesar-crea-si/eviacam
```

and then run commands to install EviaCam from [officiai repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/eviacam) using below commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eviacam
```